# Powershell response not expected on -contains

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that has an if statement depending on what a variable starts with basically.

I have this code:

```
if($content -contains "fail*") {
    #Not all ID's exist/could not be created. pop up error code :(
    "match"
} else {
    #At this point, we should have a list of hardware id's identifier from our database.
    "no match"
}
```

The powershell `$_POST`'s data to my server, for a response. If that response starts with `fail` it should go down the first branch, if it returns anything else, it should go down the other branch.

My PHP code can only return 1 result right now, as I was testing this. This is my php code:

```
<?
    include("db-connector.php");
    echo "fail - ".$_POST['device'];
?>
```

The included file contains no output. As you can see, the result should ALWAYS go down the fail branch, but it actually doesn't. Why am I getting this result?

Comment: Read `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` carefully. If you need a wildcard use either `-like` or RegEx based `-match`

Comment: Sorry everyone, definitely a duplicate, I just didn't know what words to search for to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `-like` if you're using a wildcard to compare to.

[about_Comparison_Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)